# Gratitude for everything you all do here

Tags: discussion

This is to say 'thank you' for this powerful network built with all the supports.  There has not been an issue I have not found the answer in the forums archive.  It is just unbelievable the freedom I feel being among you all.

Comment: Thank you! Ask Ubuntu is a great community thanks to all the users who try to give a hand in gratitude for the help received, encouraging every new user to be part of it. And the best part of all is be open to share knowledge. Keep it up! :-)

Answer (score 13):

We love to hear that of course!

I should mention that we need you at least as much as you need us, because we simply *love* to do what we do here; make things work.

At the same time: **WATCH OUT!...**

If you ever think: *ah, I know the answer to this a question*, and by accident you start writing an answer, or even worse, press the button...

...The little signal-green box shows up, and you think *hey... that's funny, let's try that again*. **NO NO NO, AARRGGHH**, too late then, you'll be one of us, poor bastards as we are.

No seriously, it's good company here, and it is one of these rare places where people cooperate in a way that everyone feels it is *in their interest* to create quality, while no commerce is involved.

Good to hear it seems to work.